# Error in llvm when compiling bitcode

Tags: llvm

This is my bitcode compiled using llvm:

```
define void @.datadiv_decode2604521171261794706() {
; <label>:0:
  br label %1
  br label %6

; <label>:1:                                      ; preds = %1, %0
  %2 = phi i32 [ 0, %0 ], [ %3, %1 ]
  %3 = add i32 %2, 1
  %4 = icmp ult i32 %2, 12
  %5 = icmp ne i1 %4, i32 0
  br i1 %5, label %1, label %0

; <label>:6:                                      ; preds = %6, %0
  %7 = phi i32 [ 0, %0 ], [ %8, %6 ]
  %8 = add i32 %7, 1
  %9 = icmp ult i32 %7, 2
  %10 = icmp ne i1 %9, i32 0
  br i1 %10, label %6, label %0
}
```

And error message is :

```
Error: instruction expected to be numbered '%3'.
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

`; <label>:0:
  br label %1
  br label %6`

This is entirely wrong. Each BasicBlock should only have one terminator. Please provide the source of whatever Transform pass you've written to help locate your error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have already solved this problem. However, another error came from backend when I run my pass. Here is the link to my problem.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787823/fatal-error-error-in-backend-cannot-select-0x7793fa0-f64-xor-0x74291b0-co)