# fatal error: error in backend: Cannot select: 0x7793fa0: f64 = xor 0x74291b0, Constant:i8<-3>

Tags: llvm

This is the error message when I use the following command:

```
clang++ test.cpp -mypass -fno-use-cxa-atexit
```

to compile my `test.cpp` source file directly with my transform pass.

```
Error message:
fatal error: error in backend: Cannot select: 0x7793fa0: f64 = xor 0x74291b0,
      Constant:i8<-3>
  0x74291b0: f64,ch = load<LD8[%1064](align=1)> 0x732b440, 0x74317d0, undef:i64
    0x74317d0: i64 = add 0x7794390, 0x7428f10
      0x7794390: i64 = shl 0x7464360, Constant:i8<3>
        0x7464360: i64 = sign_extend 0x7430d50
          0x7430d50: i32,ch = CopyFromReg 0x732b440, Register:i32 %vreg212
            0x77949b0: i32 = Register %vreg212
        0x77bbd40: i8 = Constant<3>
      0x7428f10: i64 = X86ISD::Wrapper TargetGlobalAddress:i64<[27 x double]* @_ZZ9test_mainiPPcE5valsA.291> 0
        0x77904a0: i64 = TargetGlobalAddress<[27 x double]* @_ZZ9test_mainiPPcE5valsA.291> 0
    0x7431990: i64 = undef
  0x77bbdb0: i8 = Constant<-3>
In function: .datadiv_decode15430557481081536446
clang-3.9: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)
clang version 3.9.1 (tags/RELEASE_391/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/oubotong/obf/bin
clang-3.9: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://llvm.org/bugs/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang-3.9: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************
```

However, when I use the following command to compile seperately:

```
clang++ -emit-llvm -S test.cpp -mypass -fno-use-cxa-atexit
```

This  command generate `test.ll` and then use:

```
llvm-as test.ll -o test.bc
```

to generate `test.bc` and finally use:

```
lli test.bc
```

to run the program.
There are no errors and my program works well.
Then why the error came when I compile the `test.cpp` directly?
Here is part of my source code in pass:

```
LoadInst *Load=builder.CreateLoad(gvar);
Load->setAlignment(8);
Value* indexList[2] = {ConstantInt::get(variable->getType(), 0), variable};                                 
Value *const_key=builder.getInt8(key);
Value *GEP=builder.CreateGEP(gvar,ArrayRef<Value*>(indexList, 2),"arrayIdx");
LoadInst *loadElement=builder.CreateLoad(GEP);
loadElement->setAlignment(1);
Value *Xor = builder.CreateXor(loadElement,const_key,"xor");
StoreInst *Store = builder.CreateStore(Xor, GEP);
Store->setAlignment(1);
```

Comment: The error is in the backend. What happens if you compile `test.bc` to an executable?

Comment: If I continue using `llc test1.bc -o test1.s` command to generate an assemble file `test1.s` and using `clang++ test1.s -o test1.out` to generate the excutable file. No error occurs during this process.

Comment: Please submit the transformed IR.

Comment: The `test1.ll` is very complex so I submit part of the source code which I think may cause the error. I have already updated my problem above.

Comment: try post the IR to gist.github.com and add the link to the question?

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Could you please message me your email address so I can contact you when I finish posting the IR or come across other error in llvm?

Comment: llvm-dev mailing list is probably a better place to ask questions. As for your code, I suspect those ``setAlignment`` is the issue. Still need the IR and/or more code though

Comment: I think I got your point. I try to print the type of my `const_key` and the type of `loadElement` and find that sometime their type don't match each other. I am going to create the key according to the type of element.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late answer but actually, when you have the `.ll` file, the `llc` command can give you some meaningful hints on why things aren't compiling.

The `Cannot select` error is way more cryptic.